# DB2 Registry and Configuration Settings

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst

I am setting up the `DB2 10.1 (FP2)` environment on `AIX 7.1` for `IBM Worklight 5.0.5`.

Are the following registry settings acceptable ?

```
DB2_SKIPINSERTED=YES
DB2_OPTPROFILE=YES
DB2_INLIST_TO_NLJN=YES
DB2_MINIMIZE_LISTPREFETCH=YES
DB2_EVALUNCOMMITTED=YES
DB2_ANTIJOIN=EXTEND
DB2_SKIPDELETED=YES
```

I could not find recommendations for DB2 settings, so using WCS settings as a starting point.

Are there any recommendations for dbm and db configuration settings for Worklight?

Thanks 
Sathyaram

Answer (score 2):

As to whether these are set correctly, the answer, as usual, is ...it depends. ;-)

These enhance concurrency, since a connection is less affected by uncommitted rows of another connection (with certain isolation levels).  Whether this is desirable is dependant on the type of work being done.  See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0012389.html )

```
DB2_SKIPINSERTED=YES
DB2_SKIPDELETED=YES
DB2_EVALUNCOMMITTED=YES
```

Another important setting for enhanced concurrency is the DB CFG parameter CUR_COMMIT - which is ON by default now.

This is obsolete now and refers to the use of Optimization Profiles (sort of like Hints for DB2).  Search the Info Center on this topic.

```
DB2_OPTPROFILE=YES
```

These are among the registry variables which can change the behavior of optimizer decisions (usually to restrict the optimizer making it's own decisions).  Generally, they should only be set when recommended by a particular application (such as Worklight or SAP, etc.) or by IBM Support as the result of a performance engagement.  Note that the affects of the variable should always be rechecked when moving to a different DB2 release (e.g., v9 to v10), as there are always improvements to the optimizer and thus the significance of these variables.

```
DB2_INLIST_TO_NLJN=YES
DB2_MINIMIZE_LISTPREFETCH=YES
DB2_ANTIJOIN=EXTEND
```